# How can I change the marker color in Syncfusion Scheduler for holidays using C# and ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, scheduler, syncfusion

I'm using asp.net core C# , syncfusion scheduler.

I want to change the marker color

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LNyy.png)

like this picture. I want to change the marker color to red when that day is holiday

I need to set the holiday for myself.

Comment: Please post the codes about how syncfusion scheduler you have used now.

Answer (score 0):

To change the marker color to red when a day is a holiday, you can utilize the `renderCell` event in the Syncfusion scheduler. Below is an example of how you can achieve this.

```
@using Syncfusion.EJ2.Schedule

<ejs-schedule id="schedule" width="100%" height="650px" selectedDate="new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 6)" renderCell="onRenderCell">
   
    <e-schedule-views>
        <e-schedule-view option="Month"></e-schedule-view>
    </e-schedule-views>
    <e-schedule-eventsettings dataSource="@ViewBag.datasource">
        <e-eventsettings-fields>
            <e-field-subject name="Subject" title="Service Type"></e-field-subject>
            <e-field-location name="Location" title="Patient Name"></e-field-location>
            <e-field-description name="Description" title="Summary"></e-field-description>
            <e-field-starttime name="StartTime" title="From"></e-field-starttime>
            <e-field-endtime name="EndTime" title="To"></e-field-endtime>
        </e-eventsettings-fields>
    </e-schedule-eventsettings>
</ejs-schedule>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onRenderCell(args) {
        if (args.element.classList.contains('e-work-cells')) {
            var schObj = document.querySelector('.e-schedule').ej2_instances[0];
            let ele = document.createElement('div');
            let text = getHoliday(args.date);
            if (text) {
                ele.innerHTML = text;
                (args.element).appendChild(ele.firstChild);
            }
            if (args.element.classList.contains('e-current-date') && args.element.lastChild && args.element.lastChild.innerHTML == "Holiday") {
                // Here we applied the class to 
                ej.base.addClass([args.element], ['e-currentHoliday-date']);
            }
        }
    }
    function getHoliday(value) {
        let holidayCollection = [new Date(2023, 4, 28), new Date(2023, 4, 9), new Date(2023, 4, 23), new Date(2023, 4, 24), new Date(2023, 4, 25), new Date(2023, 4, 26)];
        for (let i = 0; i < holidayCollection.length; i++) {
            if ((value.getTime() - holidayCollection[i].getTime()) == 0) {
                return '<div class="holiday-text">Holiday</div>';
            }
        }
        return null;
    };
</script>
```

You need to define the styling for the `e-currentHoliday-date` class to set the marker color to red:

```
<style>
    .holiday-text {
        float: right;
        margin: -20px 2px 0 0;
        background: #EA7A57;
    }

    .e-schedule .e-month-view .e-currentHoliday-date .e-date-header, .e-schedule .e-month-agenda-view .e-currentHoliday-date .e-date-header {
        background-color: red !important;
    }
</style>
```

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YXad.png)

Comment: Thanks for your help !
I was able to resolve it successfully ! thanks to the code you provided!